# Why can I not print this input a second time in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I am very new to OCaml and am attempting to learn and write a program at the same time.  I am writing a palindrome program.  I am attempting to get a string from the user such as `d e v e d` or `Hello World!` or `loud` all of the preceding are valid user input.  I need to read these strings and display them then reverse them and check if it is a palindrome or not.  I did the following code...

```
print_string "Enter a string: ";
let str = read_line () in
Printf.printf "%s\n" str;;

Printf.printf "%s\n" str;;
```

this works fine and will give the print, `Enter a string: d e v e d` or `Enter a string: Hello World!` The issue comes when I try to add another `Printf.printf "%s\n" str;;` into the code.  it gives me an error of `File "main.ml", line 5, characters 21-24:
Error: Unbound value str` with line 5 being the line of the 2nd `Printf.printf` statement.  I have tried this with no `;` for both of the print statements, with 1 or with 2 and I get the same error each time.  Does anyone with more OCaml knowledge know why I get this error.

Comment: It may be a good idea to also post the code the is giving you troubles.

Comment: @norok2 I did, I just didn't post the extra Printf statement. Which I clearly defined in the paragraph below the code I did post.  That was all the code I had.  Just 5 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of your use of `in` your code parses as:

```
(let str = read_line () in Printf.printf "%s\n" str);;
```

and then a completely separate:

```
Printf.printf "%s\n" str;;
```

So `str` is local to the first `printf`.

You want:

```
let str = read_line ();;
Printf.printf "%s\n" str;;
Printf.printf "%s\n" str;;
```

which is three separate definitions. The first defines a global variable `str`.